# classNotPreparedForTest exception, using JUNIT5, MOCKITO and POWERMOCKITO

Tags: junit, mockito, junit5, powermock, powermockito

We are using JUNIT 5.3.2, MOCKITO 2+ and powermock 2.0.0

I have added JUNIT and Mockito as testImplementation only.
Powermockito as runTimeOnly

I am getting classNotPreparedForTest exception while I exceute Powermockito.mockstatic(Classfile.class);

Even though to my test class I have used @RunWith and @PrepareTest

I did try to look out for some answers could find any helpful suggestions to fix the exception, looking forward for some answers

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant code in a [mre].